# inserting json into solr 5.5

Tags: java, solr, solrj

The following is my code:

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/update/json?wt=json&commit=true");

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("{\n"
                                + "   \"id\": \"1\",\n"
                                + "   \"title\": \"Doc 1\"\n"
                                + "}", "UTF-8");

entity.setContentType("application/json");
postRequest.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

But when I am trying to add Json to Solr 5.5.0, the below exception is raised:

`{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":2},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"Unknown command 'id' at [9]","code":400}}`

Answer (score 1):

In different Solr versions there have been several changes/bugfixes about handling json, but here the best thing is just to take the hint the error msg gives you, and act accordingly.

Solr is expecting a 'command', so you should enclose your doc in an 'add' element so the String looks like this:

```
{
  "add": {
   "doc": {
    "id": "1",
    "title":"Doc 1"
    }
   }
}
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below. Ignore those "\n". You wont need them.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://solrHost.com:8983/solr/update/json");
StringEntity input = new StringEntity("{\"firstName\":\"Hello\",\"lastName\":\"World\"}");
input.setContentType("application/json");
postRequest.setEntity(input);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```